# Inserting unicode characters in vim

Tags: vim, unicode, digraphs

I would like a quick and easy way to insert certain unicode characters into text files with vim that I use often, for example, the British Pound Sterling and the tick characters instead of typing:

```
i C-v u00A3 = £
i C-v u2713 = ✓
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TL;DR

After some digging around, I was able to come up with these:

#### Digraph Shortlist

```
Insert Digraphs
i C-k OK = ✓
i C-k $$ = £
i C-k Eu = €
i C-k XX = ✗
i C-k TM = ™
i C-k Co = ©
i C-k Rg = ®
i C-k /- = †
i C-k RT = √
i C-k *1 = ☆
i C-k *2 = ★

NB: tmux maps C-k so unmap it for vim in tmux.conf
```

This new functionality was added to Vim 8.2 released in May 2019.

These are entered from *insert mode* using **`C-k <2letter shortcut>`**

Type `:digraph` or just `:dig` to display a list of all possible digraphs in Vim.

#### P.S.

Not to be confused with *diacritics* which are character accents like the German umlaut `ü`.

Hope this helps someone out there too.

Comment: Digraphs have been around for a bit actually, and they include some diacritics

Answer (score 1):

I believe the quickest and simplest way to insert the Unicode code is to add [abbreviations](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#abbreviations) for the characters you use most often:

```
:iabbrev upound <C-v>u00A3
:iabbrev utick <C-v>u2713
```

These commands adds abbreviations and makes them available in insert mode. To expand them, write the name ("upound" or "utick") followed by a non-keyword character such as comma, space, Esc, or Enter.

Comment: It seems to me like this just types "u00A3" or "u2713" instead of inserting their corresponding unicode characters...

Comment: They should be prefixed with a `<C-v>`: `:iabbrev upound <C-v>u00A3`